# What is an elegant solution to the namespace vs classname clash problem?

Tags: c#, .net, standards, standards-compliance

One of the things that annoys me a lot about .NET is the fact that name-spaces are supposed to be Pascal cased which opens to the possibility of name-space/class-name clashes.

Consider the following:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct.SalesOrder {
    public class SalesOrder {
    }
}
```

This is perfectly valid code, however consumers of `SalesOrder` as a class must now use the fully qualified name of `MyCompany.MyProduct.SalesOrder.SalesOrder` otherwise compiling causes the annoying `'MyCompany.MyProduct.SalesOrder' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'` error.

What are others doing to get around this? Some places I see others just go against the rule and use lower-case packages, this does appeal to me but I do like to conform to the standard and use proper casing. In my usage so-far I have subscribed to the notion of plural based name-space names where possible, however this sometimes just looks ugly.

My personal opinion is that .NET has got it wrong and should be using lower-cased name-spaces just like Java's packages.

Comment: Don't name your classes the same as your namespaces.  It's rarely a necessity.

Comment: Talljoe, I'm not arguing FOR my class-names to be the same as the name-space names, the problem is that sometimes clashes occur. For example, if I had a drawing product that had a namespace `MyProduct.Drawing` because I wanted it to model the `System.Drawing` namespace, but then I wanted a class called `Drawing` inside `MyProduct.Drawing`. The other problem is say that I have a product that uses `System.Drawing` and I have a class called `Design` it clashes with the `System.Drawing.Design` name-space. Again emphasising that I believe that namespaces should be all lower case.

Comment: You can use Namespace aliasing [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx] to get around this issue by making it explicit what you want:
    using Design = MyProduct.Drawing.Design;

Comment: Good point Talljoe, I had actually forgotten about namespace aliasing, fyi: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: Well, as for the `Drawing` example, you shouldn't have a class named `Drawing`. The `Drawing` name indicates it includes multiple responsibilities around drawing activities. That clearly indicates the `Drawing` class would violate the Single Responsibility Principle. Having that on mind, `Drawing` is a perfect example for namespace, not for a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally agree with you, this behavior is absolutely annoying. I usually just tend to give the namespace a more general name. In your case I would choose something like `MyCompany.MyProduct.SalesOrderManagement` or just `MyCompany.MyProduct.SalesOrders`.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I think the plural form is neater, I hate classes/namespaces with such long names, the whole .NET class libraries are full of unnecessarily long class names. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 3):

What is the purpose of having `SalesOrder` as a namespace? Namespace should be a "space" so it should cover more than a single class. Following this rule, you should not have conflicts between classes and namespaces.

Comment: Name-spaces should separate your logical project, `SalesOrder` is a module, Such classes that would fit under this namespace would be `ISalesOrderService`, `SalesOrder`, `SalesOrderLine`, `HibernateSalesOrderService`. Notice the class of `SalesOrder`, I'm trying to establish a generalised rule for what the name-space name where clashes occur.